# GCP IAM management screen. Is this a bug or my misunderstanding?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

You can see `Table A` of permissions in GCP's `IAM and Administration > IAM` page.
`Table A` has an item called `Analyzed Permissions (Extra / Total)`.
You can see more detailed `Table B` for that role by clicking on a value such as `2/4` of this item.

Normally this is fine, but the information in `Table B` appears to be inverted when all permissions for a role are extra or when there are no extra permissions. Is this a bug? Or is it my misunderstanding?

(I use the GCP management screen in the Japanese version, so it may not be reproduced in the English version.)

The explanation may be difficult to understand because it is abstract, so I will give a concrete example.

Suppose the role "Write Log" for a service account is listed as `0/1` in `Table A`.
This indicates that "Write Log" has no extra permissions (all permissions "Write Log" for that role have been used in the last 90 days).
However, all permissions are displayed in the "Extra Permissions" column on `Table B`, which is inconsistent (inverted) with `Table A`.

Conversely, if the permissions for a role look like `6/6` in `Table A`, it means that none of the permissions for that role are used,
If you open `Table B` for such a role, it will be treated as if there is no "extra permissions" field and everything is in use (inverted to `Table A`).

However, roles that are used halfway, such as `3/7` in `Table A`, are displayed correctly in `Table B`.

screen shot:
[image: screen shot]

Comment: Can you try a screenshot even if in Japanese?

Comment: ok. I'll upload screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAM recommender analyse the usage of permission over the last 90 days. It shows `X/Y` where X is the number of unused permission, and Y the total number of permissions granted.

- If there is X=0, the table B show you only the current used permission, not the ununsed, because they aren't

[image]

- If there is X=Y, the column for the "currently use permission" is empty and all the existing permissions are in the unused column

[image]

- If there is X>0 adn X<Y, the table B show a mix between the list of currently used permission, and the unused.

[image]

If you have a light bulb, it's because IAM recommander has found better roles, and you have propositions to increase your security.

Comment: "If there is X=0, the table B show you only the current used permission" Yes. But "余分な権限" on table B means "un-used permission". So in this case, X=0 but table B shows un-used permission (but actualy, I use that permission).  Is it translation error of GCP?

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, it's a translation mistake! I undate my answer